# Framework not found EXLocation, OpenSSL while generating archive react native ios xcode

Tags: ios, react-native, frameworks

I have been trying to generate the archive for the last 2 days. I have created react native project. It's run successfully on the device. But when I am trying to generate the archive to upload on a test flight. It gives me errors.

[image]

My RN version is 0.64, Xcode 12.5.

Here is my pod file:

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native-unimodules/cocoapods.rb'

platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'XXXX' do
   use_unimodules!
  config = use_native_modules!
  
  use_react_native!(
                    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
                    # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
                    :hermes_enabled => false
                    )
                    


                    target 'XXXXXTests' do
                      inherit! :complete
                      # Pods for testing
                    end
                    
                    # Enables Flipper.
                    #
                    # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
                    # you should disable the next line.
                    use_flipper!({ 'Flipper-Folly' => '2.5.3', 'Flipper' => '0.87.0', 'Flipper-RSocket' => '1.3.1' })
                    
                    post_install do |installer|
                      react_native_post_install(installer)
                    end
end
```

I have tried pod deintegrated and installed pod again many times. but it doesn't work

Comment: hi i am getting same problem. did you get any solution of it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For me, it was a different app target version in Podfile(platform:ios, '11.0') and in the Xcode project file

[image]

It causing Archiving job to fail in the CI pipeline.
Matching both values fixed an issue! Hope this helps anyone.

Comment: you saved me! Thanks:)

Comment: This worked for me too. After upgrading to RN 0.65 pod platform was set to 11 but my target in xcode was 10